MacBook Pro M1 shuts down after login
I have a problem with my MacBook Pro M1 Pro. I bought it in 2022, and now, when I type my password, it shuts down immediately and does not turn on again, even if I press the power button. For the MacBook to turn on again, I need to plug in the charger. This error always occurs the same way: after typing my password and pressing enter, the MacBook shuts down.

Welcome to Ask Different.  Would you be able to edit this to ask a clear question? Typically we expect people to show what research they do to solve their question. For example if your question is where can you sell this for parts or scrap, you might document how you searched for a dealer? Or the question is how to find a repair tech, you might explain how locate.apple.com doesn’t have repairs listed for Antarctica, for instance..  what’s the practical problem you face so we don’t have to assume what we guess is your problem. It could be just you want to erase the Mac and start over?

For now, I’ll close as what looks to be a duplicate thread but if you edit a different question than the duplicate. Please flag for review.

I would take the Mac to an Apple Store or other authorised repair shop.
